# If $(v_k)_k$ is bounded and $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_C(B_R)$, does the inequality $\int_{B_R} v_k^2 |\nabla\varphi| dx \le c$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $B_R$ be the ball (centered in $0$) of radius $R>0$ and let $\varphi\in C_C^{\infty}(B_R)$, where $C_C^{\infty}(B_R)$ stands for the set of $C^{\infty}$ with compact support functions.
Moreover, let $(v_k)_k$ be a bounded sequence. My question is: Can I conclude that
$$\int_{B_R} v_k^2 |\nabla\varphi| dx \le c,$$
where $c>0$ denotes a constant?

About me the answer is yes, because $|\nabla\varphi|$ is continuous over a compact set so it is bounded and $v_k^2$ is bounded since it is $v_k$. Could someone please tell me if I am right or I miss something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are correct, if by $v_k$ bounded you mean that there exists $M>0$ such that $|v_k(x)|\leq M$ for a.e. $x\in B_R$ and all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Jose27 actually $v_k$ is bounded in a suitable Banach space $X$; I mean $M>0$ exists such that $\|v_k\|_X\le M$. The conclusion is the same?

Comment: It really, really depends on $X$, and this is info that should be on the main question: It's false, for instance, if $X=L^1(B_R)$, true if $X=L^2(B_R)$, etc.

Comment: @Jose27 In this case, $X = H^1_0(B_R)\cap L^{\infty}(B_R)$. I guess it is true (based on your previuos comment), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, either of those spaces will give you what you want. The intersection even more so.

Comment: @Jose27 thank you very much for you help!